# Is it possible to use a touchscreen monitor on a Mac Mini?

Tags: mac, display, mac-mini, touchscreen

How would I go about interacting with my late 2012 Mac Mini via a touchscreen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - they connect over USB like a mouse and over whatever display method you want to push the video.

Since the OS isn’t touch based, you basically emulate the mouse and it’s not going to change the OS how it behaves.

Comment: thanks.  is there anything I need to look for or just any touchscreen with a USB out will do?

Comment: That being said, @WalrustheCat make sure the touch screen is MacOS compatible! For example, the Dell P2418HT will not work with MacOS (according to an answer on B&H’s website).

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, depending on which screen you buy. (TouchBase) is the key to getting it to work. Once at the website, join and log in first. Then follow simple instructions that they give you... Pay for the (drivers) then download and install...
I do music production, needless to say it sped up my work flow by far... And it was worth the 90 bucks.... Oh and finger gestures work as well, I'm still learning that part. Also TouchBase's control panel allows you to alter configurations within for an ultimate experience... I'm running a Mac mini (2018) i7, 16gb... with AZUZ ZenScreen Touch MB16AMT